# What does $\Lsh$ mean?

Tags: notation

Source: [Wikipedia (permalink)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nuclear_weapon_yield&oldid=775547980#Calculating_yields_and_controversy), in the formula for the heat capacity ratio:
$$Y=\biggl({Cp\over \Lsh Cv}\biggr)$$
The $\LaTeX$ command is `\Lsh`.

Comment: I think that, thermodynamically speaking, your capital Y should be a $\gamma$ (gamma letter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This picture was introduced with the version of [16:08, 10 June 2016‎](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nuclear_weapon_yield&oldid=724650354)‎ with the comment "Replacing the typed formulae with the picture formulae". This replacement went wrong.

The previous version of [07:45, 11 April 2016‎](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nuclear_weapon_yield&oldid=714689661) still uses the string

```
γ = Cp/ Cv
```

The link [heat ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) in the text refernces a page with the picture

[image]

So the correct formula seems to be

$$\gamma=\frac{C_P}{C_V}$$

I therefore changed this in the  Wikipedia article, Version of [00:00, 20 April 2017‎](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nuclear_weapon_yield&oldid=776271611)

Comment: +1 Good use of Wikipedia history. Why not fix this on Wikipedia?

Comment: @EthanBolker: I already changed it

Answer (score 4):

Typographical / transcription error? Follow the link to "Heat capacity ratio" and you see the formula $$\gamma=\frac{C_P}{C_V}.$$ That weird `\Lsh` symbol looks vaguely like the TeX gamma. And so does $Y$.